# Javascript to scroll an iframe? (Like Facebook Messages)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an iframe scroll behind my footer div, so I don't want the page itself to scroll at all. If you've got Facebook you'll know what I mean when I say I'd like it to be like Facebook Messages. The scroll bar scrolls the messages div rather than the actual page.

The HTML I have right now is:

```
<div class="content">
    <iframe src="http://192.168.0.122/bf2sclone/?pid=28999999" style="width:100%;height:200px;"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

And the CSS I have is:

```
div.footer {
    width: 980px;
    height: 114px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../images/footer.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: The iframe should have a scrollbar, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Do you have to use an iFrame? The Facebook message bar does not use an iFrame.

Comment: I didn't expect Facebook to use an iframe. My knowledge however is limited so I have to. Otherwise I'd do it all with Javascript.
The iframe does have a scrollbar (did until I disabled it) however I want that scrollbar to appear as the main scrollbar of the page so it scrolls behind my footer div just like Facebook Messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook message doesn't use iframe, you can get this effect by set the left part of the page `fixed`(set in css: `position: fixed`).
So, just set footer fixed, and it should work fine.

Comment: I didn't expect it to, but my knowledge is limited.
The problem I'm having is I have an image with transparent background as my footer, and a margin below my footer. So I want the iframe to scroll behind the footer image (so I can see it through the transparent spaces) but not into the margin space, so the footer div is the baseline for it to stop.

Comment: Any chance anyone can give me some info on this?

Comment: @Richard Hedges Can you give an example(some website) that has this effect?

Comment: The only website I know of that does this is Facebook when you view Messages.